# How to detect the existence of non Latin characters in a string?

Tags: c#

I want to change all filenames containing non Latin characters to a random unique Latin string. But how can I detect the existence of non Latin character in the original filenames?

### Edit

The non-latin characters might be chinese, japanese, korean, arabic, umlaut, etc characters.

Comment: you have to be more specific because some latin-derived characters may not fall into `A-z`. This one, for example - `Ä`

Answer (score 6):

You could use regex:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(input, "[^a-zA-Z]"))
{
    // non-latin found
}
```

It will work for every letter different then `a` to `z` and `A` to `Z`.

If you'd like to allow digits too, use following: `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

***Non-regex solution***

You could use LINQ as well, because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
if(input.ToLower().Any(c => c <= 'a' || c >= 'z'))
{
    // non-latin found
}
```

Comment: This misses any Latin characters with accents.